# Are these fstab crypttab enties necessary?

Tags: mount, fstab

I am using a LUKS setup. I have these entries like `ubuntu--vg-root` and `ubuntu--vg-swap_1`. What are these doing exactly? Can I remove them safely?

What is the minimal setup that will get me booted? Preferably one that will not use UUIDs and will work when restored on a different machine.

`/etc/fstab/`

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=4298dc11-a19d-44bc-b1b8-5f9034ca23e7 /boot ext2 defaults 0 2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0
```

`/etc/crypttab`

```
sdb5_crypt UUID=a8757dde-d310-41c4-b840-3e56b231e07d none luks,discard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entry in `/etc/crypttab` and the first entry in `/etc/fstab` are required. Those entries are needed in order for your encrypted filesystem to be decrypted and mounted correctly to appear as a normal filesystem.

The second entry in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0
```

This entry mounts swap space. In a nutshell, swap space is RAM on your hard disk. It is used when you run out of actual RAM.

So, all in all, I would say don't modify them and keep everything. :)

Comment: During boot I am told that `ubuntu--vg-swap_1` was not found. I have no swap partition/file. I disabled it and now everything works well. What makes me wonder is that `ubuntu--vg-root` does not refer to any particular partition. Is it some sort of auto detection entry thing?

Comment: If your system is like mine, then the mismatch in mappings seems to have something to do with LVM combined with LUKS.  I wish somebody gave a more comprehensive answer because I have a system that won't boot and I could use more info to figure it out.